# GeoZoomLevel for GeoElevationData

Tags: geographics

I am trying to get a local contour map on an area of about 1.5x1.5 km^2. I am getting the following error:

"GeoElevationData::chzoom: Unable to download data for zoom level 15. Using zoom 12 instead"

The map obtained is of pretty low resolution. Is there a way to get zoom levels greater than 12?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably not. The data source is mostly from [NASA's SRTM project](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-shuttle-radar-topography-mission-srtm-1-arc?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects), which has a maximum resolution of about 30 metres per pixel. A zoom level of 12 is somewhere around 40 metres per pixel, while zoom level 15 is closer to 5 metres per pixel. You may have some luck searching for open elevation datasets from the government of your area and using those.

Comment: @Carl Lang. Thanks for your feedback. I feared this was the case. We have free government data in my area. I will need to investigate the available formats in the resolution I need, and how to best import them into MMA.